# how to pass no_ready_check option to createClient in Redis 4

Tags: node.js, redis

I am trying to upgrade from redis 3 to redis 4. Previously I was creating the redis client like this

```
redis.createClient({ host: redisHost, port: redisPort, no_ready_check: true})
```

After upgrading to Redis 4, I found that host and port were moved under 'socket' so now it is

```
redis.createClient({ socket: { host: redisHost, port: redisPort }})
```

However I cannot pass the no_ready_check option as I get the following error:

> Argument of type '{ socket: { port: number; host: string; }; no_ready_check: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RedisClientOptions<RedisModules, RedisFunctions, RedisScripts>'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'no_ready_check' does not exist in type 'RedisClientOptions<RedisModules, RedisFunctions, RedisScripts>'.

I cannot find anywhere online an information about how to pass this option to redis client in Redis 4

Has anyone dealt with the same issue?